# When Someone Hits Enter Break Text

Tags: php, html, line

I am creating a forum software for my first time I know most of PHP just not a few things.

Anyway,
Say when someone hits enter like on this 
"Like this i just hit enter"

It will display as a new line when the topic is posted how can I archive this?

Right now even if I went to a new line the post will still display like this "sssssssssssssssss" the user needs to add 
 to break it but I need to disable HTML for security reasons.

I now I could get PHP to add 
 automatically when the post is submitted but then 
 will be displayed to the users and I be disabling html.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in the PHP. It automatically converts the linebreaks to `<br>` tags.

Say if the user typed data  on the `<textarea>` of your form and when he clicks <kbd>Submit</kbd> , it reaches to your PHP page say **submit.php** , in that page you should be doing like this..

**`submit.php`**

```
<?php
$textareadata = isset($_POST['textareadata'])? nl2br(htmlspecialchars(($_POST['textareadata']))) : "Not Sent";
```

Comment: what language is the op typing ?!

Comment: PHP i am using would that be the way forum software's do it?trying to be professional
I think this will work and thanks ;)

Comment: gnack it was hard to explain....

Comment: @user279297, Did you read the manual of `nl2br()` and `htmlspecialchars()` ?

Comment: htmlspecialchars I have that should remove the <br> from the field and I actually forgot about nl2br as its been around since I did php

Comment: i'm going to google some samples now
Also everytime I press submit it will create a new line break so it duplicates it

Comment: @Downvoter , please edit this answer if you find it wrong.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Apologies, that was apparently me.  I must have finger-fumbled on the Android app.  I made an insubstantial edit to your answer and reverted the downvote.

Comment: @cheeken, Np mate. Have a great day.